# How to change content of Option<Box<SomeStruct> without moving

Tags: rust

As a beginner, I'm experimenting with some Tree/Node constructions.

How do I change the value of id, in the program below, as directly as possible, so without moving or replacing anything but the id-string itself.
My miserable attempts, commented out :)
The output of the current program is:

```
Tree { root: Some(Id(IdExpr { meta: NodeMeta { error: 0, range: 0 }, id: "ikke1234" })) }
```

The code:

```
#![allow(dead_code, unused_variables)]

#[derive(Debug)]
struct NodeMeta {
    error: i32,
    range: i32,
}

impl NodeMeta {
    fn new( ) -> NodeMeta {
        NodeMeta { 
            error: 0,
            range: 0,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct IdExpr {
    meta: NodeMeta, 
    id: String
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct NoneExpr {
    meta: NodeMeta,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Node {
    None (NoneExpr),
    Id (IdExpr)
}


#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tree {
    root: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl Tree {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Tree { root: None }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut tree = Tree::new();
    let id_expr = Node::Id(IdExpr {
        meta: NodeMeta::new(),
        id: String::from("ikke1234")
    });

    tree.root = Some(Box::new(id_expr));
    println!("{:?}", tree);

    // if let Some(mut the_root) = tree.root {
    //     if let Node::Id(mut id_expr) = the_root.deref_mut(){
    //         println!("The id is {:?}", id_expr.id);
    //         id_expr.id = String::from("CHANGED!");
    //     }
    // }
    // //2nd look at root->id
    // if let Some(root_again) = tree.root {
    //     if let Node::Id(mut id_expr) = *root_again {
    //         println!("The id is {:?}", id_expr.id);
    //     }
    // }
}
```

Comment: In order to not move values you have to borrow `&mut` or match with a `ref` [identifier pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#identifier-patterns)

Comment: Using `deref_mut()` manually is a code smell. It is usually only used by the compiler; it is meant to be an automatic thing that lives inside of the `.` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this.

```rs
if let Some(ref mut the_root) = tree.root {
    if let Node::Id(id_expr) = the_root.as_mut() {
        id_expr.id = String::from("ref mut");
    }
}
println!("{:?}", tree);

if let Some(the_root) = &mut tree.root {
    if let Node::Id(id_expr) = the_root.as_mut() {
        id_expr.id = String::from("&mut");
    }
}
println!("{:?}", tree);

if let Some(the_root) = tree.root.as_mut() {
    if let Node::Id(id_expr) = the_root.as_mut() {
        id_expr.id = String::from("as mut");
    }
}
println!("{:?}", tree);

if let Some(Node::Id(id_expr)) = tree.root.as_deref_mut() {
    id_expr.id = String::from("as deref mut");
}
println!("{:?}", tree);
```

The `ref mut` method will always work. You can use this with any enum.

The `&mut` method also always works. `the_root` gets automatically bound with `ref mut` since ownership is not available.

For `Option` specifically, you can use `as_mut`, which turns `&mut Option<T>` into `Option<&mut T>`. Then in the pattern `Some(the_root)`, `the_root` will obviously become `&mut T`.

And for this exact case, there's [`as_deref_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref_mut), which references and derefs the inner value at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is:

- `Option::as_mut()`, which can convert a `&mut Option<T>` into an `Option<&mut T>`
- `Box::as_mut()`, which returns a `&mut` reference to its content.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut tree = Tree::new();
    let id_expr = Node::Id(IdExpr {
        meta: NodeMeta::new(),
        id: String::from("ikke1234"),
    });

    tree.root = Some(Box::new(id_expr));
    println!("{:?}", tree);

    if let Some(the_root) = tree.root.as_mut() {
        if let Node::Id(id_expr) = the_root.as_mut() {
            println!("The id is {:?}", id_expr.id);
            id_expr.id = String::from("CHANGED!");
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", tree);
}
```

```
Tree { root: Some(Id(IdExpr { meta: NodeMeta { error: 0, range: 0 }, id: "ikke1234" })) }
The id is "ikke1234"
Tree { root: Some(Id(IdExpr { meta: NodeMeta { error: 0, range: 0 }, id: "CHANGED!" })) }
```

Note that that `id_expr` is of type `&mut IdExpr` because it gets matched to a `&mut Node`. This is due to the virtue of the [match ergonomics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about how to explain this part and I didn't really find the words. Thanks.

Comment: @cafce25 Like that?

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it gave a couple of alternatives, even though you explained it better. I could only pick one answer :)

Comment: Don't worry, I don't mind :D